# Event for multiple elements with the same class name

Tags: javascript

I have the following [code:](http://jsfiddle.net/Nn85Q/)

```
var abbrs = document.getElementsByClassName("hover");
abbrs.onmouseover=function() {
     console.log(this);
};
```

It should trigger when I hover over an element with the class "hover", but it is not working. 
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `console.log(abbrs);` Then read http://www.kirupa.com/html5/handling_events_for_many_elements.htm

Comment: You are not iterating over the node list and binding the event handler to each element.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about that "small" detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As its name suggests `document.getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, with the `hover` as their className, so you can do it like:

```
var i=0,
  len = abbrs.length,
  abbrs = document.getElementsByClassName("hover");

for( ; i < len ; i++){
    abbrs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        //...
    });
}
```

Although it answers the question but in terms of a better coding practice we better avoid from creating functions in loops. So the better practice could be something like this:

```
var i=0,
  len = abbrs.length,
  abbrs = document.getElementsByClassName("hover");

fnction addEvent(abbr){
    abbr.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event){
        //...
    });
}

for( ; i < len ; i++){
    addEvent(abbrs[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName returns either a NodeList or HTMLCollection depending on your current browser and version.

To add event listeners to all of the items in the "abbrs" collection/list you would need to do:

```
for(i=0; i< abbrs.length; i++) {
  abbrs[i].onmouseover=function() {...};
}
```

Alternately, using jQuery:

```
$(".hover").on("mouseover", function() {...});
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below (I assume you are not using jquery)

```
    var abbrs = document.getElementsByClassName("hover");

    var index,l=abbrs.length;
    for (index = 0; index < l; ++index) {
        console.log(abbrs[index]);
        abbrs[index].onmouseover = function() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }
```