# Modal is not working for series of button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created series of  button in table field.  Now, since the *id* for all the button is same I want the modal is work for all the button but it is working only for the first button.

```js
<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("mbutton");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

```css
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sl++;
       echo "<tr><td>". $sl. "</td><td>". $row['name']. "</td><td>". $row['Total_Trip']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Amount']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Pay']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Due']."</td><td>"."<button id='mbutton'>Pay</button><button id='mbutton'>Report</button>"."</td></tr>";
      }
```

```html
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Pay to</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
     <form>
      <label>Payment Amount</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="paymodal" placeholder="Amount"><br>
      <input type="submit" name="smitModal">
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you update your code snippet?, It's throwing an error

Comment: @vicnoob,Table is creating through the loop of PHP code. I've copied the code from IDE and it's working on my system except the problem I've mention in question.

Answer (score 2):

`id` is unique attribute value for each element so that the document will only get the first element with corresponding `id`. You can use `class` instead.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("mbutton");
```

Comment: Have you changed `<button id='mbutton'>` to `<button class='mbutton'>`?

Comment: yes, I've change it and check it with keep it or remove id. Results are same none working.

Comment: I have updated the syntax for `getElementsByClassName`. Please try again

Comment: I've change the syntax as you have written but it's not working.

Comment: Since your `btn` now is an array of document object, you cannot use `btn.onclick`. If you use JQuery try `$(".btn")` or else please take a look to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22053859/event-for-multiple-elements-with-the-same-class-name

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).` So should never put same ID for every button.

If you use Jquery, you can try the answer above by Minh Duc, if not, please try to bind `onclick` to every button, or to the column contain it (because JS event is bubbling). You can try like this with your PHP code:

```
      while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sl++;
       echo "<tr><td>". $sl. "</td><td>". $row['name']. "</td><td>". $row['Total_Trip']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Amount']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Pay']."</td><td>".$row['Total_Due']."</td>
       <td onclick="onclickHandler()">"."<button onclick="onclickHandler()" id='mbutton'>Pay</button><button onclick="onclickHandler()" id='mbutton'>Report</button>"."</td></tr>";
      }
```

And at your script file, add:

```
function onclickHandler () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
```

By this way the modal will display whenever you click any button in your table

Comment: ,yes, I did this.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript portion of my code i'm first using id.Than when @Minh suggest to use class, i have use it and it's become an array which need to be indexing.

Instead all of these i'm just calling the function from button all the time(Which i don't think before asking the question)

```
<button id='mbutton' onclick=btn()>Pay</button>
```

and

```
 function btn() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
```